# MS Lync 2010: Can we deploy multiple Lync Server in single domain?

Tags: deployment, lync

we have Lync server 2010 setup already in our network.
Now we need to have a development or Lab environment for development purpose. 
Here we are not allowed to use the production Lync environment.

Do we have any workaround for this?
Does anyone did such setup for Lync 2010 server?
is it possible to do it without isolating it from main domain n/w?

Answer (score 0):

This is not good to play within your production environment but you can have a separate CMS (Central Management Database) with separate instance of MS SQL Server to Lync Environment. using Topology builder. though lync Frontend and backend server would be totally separate and using same schema objects of your production environment.

Regards,

Adnan.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same situation, where by we needed to setup Lync server 2010 and have it completely seperate from the production environment.

I created a guide with server diagrams at 
http://www.frozentiger.com/lync